# PHP: make simple login page

Tags: html, forms

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\login.php

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\login.php
```

I have this error show up while running this code

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['attempt']) );
{
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('cant connect to db');
    mysql_select_db('test_user');

    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $password = (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
```

Comment: Why do you have a `;` after the `if`?

Comment: How are you accessing this page?

Comment: I think you want to check if $_POST['user'] and $_POST['password'] isset like you do attempt or make sure username and password are set correctly. They may not be set correctly if you are not posting the username and password to the login page, such as accessing login.php directly.

Answer (score 2):

That means those associative keys are not in your `$_POST` array, which means one of two things:

- Your form fields aren't using the `name="user"` and `name="password"` attributes
- Your form tag is omitting `method="post"` attribute

Comment: hey Thanks a lot its really helpful .. and i made major mistake and i dont even catch that ..